# Где может быть ошибка при слиянии двух адаптеров android

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

У меня в приложении я работаю со списками входящих и исходящих сообщений. Заполняются эти списки данными с сервера, которые приходят в `json`. Вот класс-модель:

```
public class Message {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("subject")
    @Expose
    private String subject;
    @SerializedName("can_delete")
    @Expose
    private boolean can_delete;
    @SerializedName("new") 
    private int newField;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("receiver_name")
    @Expose
    private String receiver_name;
    @SerializedName("sender_name")
    @Expose
    private String sender_name;
    @SerializedName("attach")
    @Expose
    private boolean attachment;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public boolean isAttachment() {
        return attachment;
    }

    public void setAttachment(boolean attachment) {
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getReceiver_name() {
        return receiver_name;
    }

    public String getSender_name() {
        return sender_name;
    }
}
```

как можно заметить с из кода, для класса, у меня есть имя отправителя и имя получателя, это разная информация, и она должна быть вставлена в список только когда я запрашиваю определенный вид сообщения. Вот два адаптера:

```
    public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageHolder> {
        private List<Message> messageList;
        private Context ctx;
        private static final String keyIncomingMessageId = "incoming_message_id";

        MessageAdapter(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
            this.messageList = messageList;
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MessageHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
            return new MessageHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageHolder holder, int position) {
            final Message message = messageList.get(position);

            holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());
            holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());

            DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
            String isoString = message.getDate();
            try {
                Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
                System.out.println(dateString);
                SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                String timeString = timeFormat.format(date);
                holder.tvDate.setText(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException ignored) {
            }


            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                    intent.putExtra(MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyIncomingMessageId, message.getId());
                    ctx.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Long pressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return messageList.size();
        }


        class MessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;

            MessageHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
                tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
                tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);

            }


   }
}
```

вот второй адаптер:

```
public class MessageAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter2.SenderHolder> {
    private List<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;
    private static final String keyOutboundMessageId = "outbound_message_id"; // для исходящих

    MessageAdapter2(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SenderHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new SenderHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SenderHolder holder, int position) {
        final Message message = messageList.get(position);

        holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());

        DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
        String isoString = message.getDate();
        try {
            Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            String timeString = timeFormat.format(date);
            holder.tvDate.setText(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                intent.putExtra(MessageAdapter2.class.getSimpleName() + keyOutboundMessageId, message.getId());
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Long pressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }


    class SenderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;

        SenderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
            tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        }
    }
}
```

и вот третий адаптер который я хочу сделать вместо двух:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.SenderHolder> {

    private List<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;
    private static final String MessageId = "message_id"; // для исходящих

    ListAdapter(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SenderHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new SenderHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SenderHolder holder, int position) {
        final Message message = messageList.get(position);


        holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());

        DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
        String isoString = message.getDate();
        try {
            Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            String timeString = timeFormat.format(date);
            holder.tvDate.setText(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                intent.putExtra(MessageAdapter2.class.getSimpleName() + MessageId, message.getId());
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Long pressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    class SenderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;

        SenderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
            tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        }
    }
}
```

я не могу понять, как определять какую функцию вызывать для получения имени отправителя или получателя. Нужно какое-то условие вставить но не могу придумать какое. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как таковой ошибки не было, просто я не дописал пару строк в адаптер. При вызове адаптера ему нужно передавать вид сообщения, которым вы хотите заполнить ваш список. Вот вызов моего адаптера:

```
messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
```

как видно из кода, в адаптер я передаю еще и вид сообщения `integer`. Дальше вот конструктор моего адаптера:

```
ListAdapter(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx, int type) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.type = type;
    }
```

и дальше я использую условный оператор для проверки входящей переменной, и в зависимости от того какая эта переменная, такую функцию я и вызываю:

```
if (type == 0)
{
holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());
}
else if(type == 1)
{
holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
}
```

конечно можно использовать и `switch-case` но я надеюсь что идея в целом понятна. Надеюсь мой ответ будет кому-то полезен.

Comment: вам нужно узнать про переопределение метода getItemViewType()

Comment: @pavlofff, не очень понимаю о чем идет речь, если честно

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, `getItemViewType()` в данном случае не обязателен - он необходим когда в одном списке нужно выводить элементы разного вида - те есть не просто разный текст, а ещё и компоновка отличается

Comment: @woesss, либо я туплю, либо я туплю, я не могу понять какое отношение имеет `getItemViewType()` к моему вопросу, я посмотрел то в коде этой функции нету, я так понимаю что прозвучало предложение использовать эту функцию?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, pavlofff предложил Вам узнать про этот метод, а я пояснил, что в данной задаче он и не требуется.

Comment: вот теперь я понял)) спасибо, но про метод я думаю все-равно нужно узнать

Comment: @woesss все же, как я понял речь идет о входящих и исходящих сообщениях в одном списке. Оформить их лучше в разных стилях, поэтому я написал про метод `getItemViewType()`. @AndrewGoroshko - узнать про [этот метод здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/177345). Более [сложный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798630/177345)