# Android ArrayAdapter с разными типами объектов

Tags: android

**Важное замечание!** Все советы в комментариях относятся к **RecyclerView** и **RecyclerView.Adapter** которые не применимы к методу класса **Spinner** `setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter)`.

Сейчас у меня есть **Spinner** с кастомным `extends ArrayAdapter<User>`.

С выводом одного типа объекта проблем нет, но я не могу сообразить и найти толковую информацию о том, как правильно создать **ArrayAdapter**, который будет принимать объекты типа **User**, **Separator**, **Bonus**. В которых совершено разные поля и методы класса. А так же, каждому объекту соответствует свой **xml** макет, так же с разными элементами в нем (**User** - **ImageView**, **TextView**; **Separator** - только **View** с **drawable background**, но это не имеет отношения к вопросу; **Bonus** - **ImageView**, **CheckBox**)

1) Я не совсем понял назначения этих методов, особенно `getViewTypeCount()`, что произойдет, если я его не переопределю? `getViewTypeCount()` я могу и без этого метода определить тип, через **instanceof** например. Просто хочу понять, последний сделан для удобства или выполняет еще какую то функцию (оптимизация может быть)?

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return super.getViewTypeCount();
}
```

2) Я использую **ViewHolder** как во многих уроках по адаптерам, т.е.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate...
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

   return convertView;
}
```

И класс **private class ViewHolder {...**, нужно ли создавать несколько **ViewHolder** под каждый тип объекта (3). И не будет ли конфликтов при переиспользовании **convertView**?

3) Как использовать несколько разных классов и xml макетов в одном ArrayAdaptere?

Comment: Переходите на RecyclerView уже

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798630/177345

Comment: @Flippy Зачем мне recycler в spinner?? Даже если recycler, вопрос остается открытым.

Comment: 1) эти методы нужны и для удобства, и для оптимизации, и для решения конфликта переиспользования (адаптер по ним определяет какой тип взять из кэша и передать в `getView(...)`). 2) можно использовать и один холдер, но если набор вью сильно отличается будет не очень удобно. 3) использовать ветвление по типам и типизировать адаптер общим предком всех моделей (можно конечно `ArrayAdapter<Object>`, но, если возможно, лучше более конкретный тип)