# Надо добавить новое свойство в обькт Crime(mRequiresPolice) и с использовать его для определения того, какое представление следует загружать

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;
    private CrimeAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);

        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);

        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateUI();

        return view;
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
        List<Crime> crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();
        mAdapter = new CrimeAdapter(crimes);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }


    //
    //ADAPTER FOR RECYCLERVIEW
    //
    private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder> {

        private final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 0;
        private final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 1;

        private List<Crime> mCrimes;

        public CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes) {
            mCrimes = crimes;
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position){
            if(position % 2 == 0){
                return TYPE_ITEM1;
            }
            return TYPE_ITEM2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCrimes.size();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v;
               if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM1){
                   v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime,parent,false);
               }else
                   v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_police,parent,false);

               return  new CrimeHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CrimeHolder holder, int position) {

            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
            holder.bind(crime);

        }


    }
    //
    //VIEWHOLDER FOR RECYCLERVIEW
    //
    private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private Crime mCrime;
        private TextView mTitleTextView;
        private TextView mDateTextView;
        private Button mButtonPolice;

        public CrimeHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
            mTitleTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
            mButtonPolice = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.police_call);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public CrimeHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {

            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false));
            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
            mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        public void bind(Crime crime) {
            mCrime = crime;
            mTitleTextView.setText(mCrime.getmTitle());
            mDateTextView.setText(mCrime.getmDate().toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    mCrime.getmTitle() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: вот [пример посложнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798630/177345) - вывод данных разных типов в айтемы с разной разметкой. Если вы опишите свою проблему намного подробнее (кнопка "править" под вопросом), то возможно получите более развернутый ответ, чем ссылки на примеры.

Comment: Считаю, что данный вопрос следует закрыть. Это упражнение из книги, автор вопроса не пытался решить данное задание, а просто хочет получить ответ.

Comment: Не совсем получить ответ, я возвращаю разные объекты ViewHolder.Но в задании написано делать это с помощью нового свойства mRequiresPolice объекта Crime(именно это мне не понятно) .

Comment: в примере по ссылке выше (втррой комментарий) добавлено свойство `type`, которое и определяет, что загружать. Если ваши объекты одного типа, то реализовать интерфейс не нужно и все несколько упроститься