# Android сообщения от одного автора собрать в одну кучу

Tags: java, android

Создаю ленту в приложении, лента отображает авторов и их сообщения, никак не могу понять, как все сообщения от одного автора совместить в одно. Т.е имя автора на верху, а все его собщения внизу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Адаптер

```
public class LentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LentAdapter.LentViewHolder>{

    private List<audioItem> audios;
    private String ao = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int gg = 0;

    audioItem a = new audioItem();

    private final int AUTHOR = 0;
    private final int AUDIO = 1;

    public LentAdapter() {
        audios = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<audioItem> getAudios() {
        return audios;
    }

    public void setAudios(List<audioItem> audios) {
        this.audios =audios;
        Collections.reverse(audios);
        ao = audios.get(audios.size()-1).getId_user();

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public LentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        if(viewType == AUDIO){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item_audio, parent, false);
        }else{
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_author, parent, false);
        }
        return new LentViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        for (audioItem a:audios) {

            if(!ao.equals(audios.get(position).getId_user())) {
                i = position-j;
            } else {
                ao = audios.get(position).getId_user();
                if(position!=gg){
                    gg=position;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(position==i) {
            return AUTHOR;
        } else {
            return AUDIO;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LentViewHolder holder, int position) {

        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        switch (type) {
            case AUTHOR:
                holder.textView_authorName.setText(audios.get(position).getId_user());
                holder.textView_audio.setText(audios.get(position).getText_Audio());

                break;
            case AUDIO:
                holder.textView_audio.setText(audios.get(position).getText_Audio());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return audios.size();
    }

    class LentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView textView_authorName;
        private TextView textView_audio;

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        public LentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView_audio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_audio);
            textView_authorName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам надо использовать другой тип для списка. Например такой: `class Data {public int type = 0; public Object data;}` заранее перегоните ваш список в такой и не придётся писать непонятный код в `getItemViewType`. Промежуточно, при преобразовании вашего списка в предложенный используете HashMap.

Comment: Так же смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798630/177345) о группировке данных в списке

Answer (score 3):

Решение до безоборазия протое. Как отметил [ЮрийСПб♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1)

нужно создать отдельный класс для списка и зарание прогнать список.

Код класса для списка

```
private int type;
private String author;
private String text;

public Page() {
}

public Page(int type, String text,String author) {
    this.author = author;
    this.type = type;
    this.text = text;
} 
//getters setters
```

Код прогона списка

```
List<Page> p= new ArrayList<Page>();
                String a = "";
                for(audioItem m: messeg){

                    if(!a.equals(m.getId_user())){
                        a=m.getId_user();
                        System.out.println(a);
                        p.add(new Page(0, m.getId_user(), m.getId_user()));
                    }
                    p.add(new Page(1, m.getText_Audio(), m.getId_user()));
                }
```

Код адаптера

```
public class LentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LentAdapter.LentViewHolder>{

private List<Page> audios;

private final int AUTHOR = 0;
private final int AUDIO = 1;

public LentAdapter() {

    audios = new ArrayList<>();

}

public List<Page> getAudios() {
    return audios;
}

public void setAudios(List<Page> audios) {
    this.audios =audios;
    //Collections.reverse(audios);


    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public LentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    if(viewType == AUDIO){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item_audio, parent, false);
    }else{
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_lent, parent, false);
    }
    return new LentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (audios.get(position).getType() == 0) {
        return AUTHOR;
    } else {

            return AUDIO;

    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LentViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    switch (type) {
        case AUTHOR:
            holder.textView_authorName.setText(audios.get(position).getAuthor());

            break;
        case AUDIO:
            holder.textView_audio.setText(audios.get(position).getText());
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return audios.size();
}

class LentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView textView_authorName;
    private TextView textView_audio;

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public LentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        textView_audio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_audio);
        textView_authorName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameUser);

    }
}
```

}
Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

значения test@test.ru повторяются, потому что были записаны в разные даты

Answer (score 2):

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return AUTHOR;
    } else {
        if (audios.get(position).getId_user() == audios.get(position - 1).getId_user()) {
            return AUDIO;
        } else {
            return AUTHOR;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, сообщения могут и вразнобой от разных авторов идти

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov возможно. Тогда надо предварительно колдовать над самим списком