# Отображение массивов двух видов в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть класс Event с параметрами, значение которых неважно.
Я хочу показывать в `RecyclerView` массив Event. Далее, я хочу группировать эти Event и когда нужно показывать в виде
[Заголовок, Событие1, Событие2], [Заголовок2, Событие3, Событие4].

Сначала я сделал главный класс `MainItem`, и `Event` и `Header`, преобразуемые в `MainItem`. Далее я сделал для них `Holder'ы`, и `Адаптер`, в котором с помощью двух `ViewType`'ов отображал массив `List<MainItem>`, в котором были либо только `Event'ы`, либо `Header'ы` и `Event'ы`.

Мне это показалось довольно костыльным, потому что `Header` и `Event` никак не были связаны. Я добавил в класс `Header` поле массив `List<Event>` для отображения событий, связанных с заголовком. Пришлось делать второй адаптер для `RecyclerView` класса `Header` и его `Event'ов`.
В главном адаптере с помощью двух View Type я отображаю либо Заголовок с Событиями, либо просто События.

Меня смущает то, что у меня в итоге получилось два адаптера.
Есть ли более оптимальный способ это всё организовать? Готовые пакеты типа `Expandable Recycler View` не предлагать.

Ниже привожу код:

Адаптер событий с заголовком:

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventHolder> {

    private List<EventItem> subItemList;

    EventAdapter(List<EventItem> subItemList) {
        this.subItemList = subItemList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EventHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_sub_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new EventHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EventHolder subItemViewHolder, int i) {
        EventItem subItem = subItemList.get(i);

        subItemViewHolder.tvSubItemTitle.setText(subItem.getEventItemTitle());
        subItemViewHolder.tvSubItemDescr.setText(subItem.getEventItemDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subItemList.size();
    }
}
```

Главный адаптер:

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainViewHolder> {

    private RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
    private List<MainItem> itemList;
    private Context context;

    MainAdapter(Context context, List<MainItem> itemList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        //View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item, viewGroup, false);
        View view;
        switch (i){
            case (Constants.ITEM_HEADER_TEXT_VIEWTYPE):
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new HeaderHolder(view);
            case (Constants.ITEM_EVENT_TEXT_VIEWTYPE):
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_sub_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new EventHolder(view);
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {


        if (itemViewHolder.getItemViewType() == Constants.ITEM_HEADER_TEXT_VIEWTYPE){
            ((HeaderHolder)(itemViewHolder)).setData(itemList.get(i));
            HeaderItem item = itemList.get(i).getHeaderItem();


            // Create layout manager with initial prefetch item count
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                    ((HeaderHolder)(itemViewHolder)).rvSubItem.getContext(),
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                    false
            );
            layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(item.getEvents().size());

            // Create sub item view adapter
            EventAdapter subItemAdapter = new EventAdapter(item.getEvents());

            ((HeaderHolder)(itemViewHolder)).rvSubItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            ((HeaderHolder)(itemViewHolder)).rvSubItem.setAdapter(subItemAdapter);
            ((HeaderHolder)(itemViewHolder)).rvSubItem.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
        }
        else{
            ((EventHolder)(itemViewHolder)).setData(itemList.get(i));

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return itemList.get(position).getViewType();
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего да, дополнительный адаптер и RecyclerView внутри RecyclerView тут не нужны. Но, т.к. не до конца (по крайней мере мне) ясно чего именно вы хотите добиться - сложо предложить однозначное решение. Воможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates для удобного использования разных типов ячеек в одном списке. Ну и отдельно надо разобраться какая вам структура данных подойдёт для вашего случая. Возможно какая-то Map с сохранением порядка добавления элементов и типом Map<Header, List<Event>>.

Comment: Но это не точно. Возможно вам как раз и надо 2 RecyclerView один в другом.

Comment: Пример адаптера с выводом данных разного типа - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798630/177345

Comment: Ознакомлюсь с обеими рекомендациями. Спасибо.